# . NET Core web API didn't working on hosted server,but its running smoothly on my development system

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

here is the response from the server
[image]

visual studio 2019 & window server 2012 r2 & .net core 2.2

sent request url "../../api/values" with ajax, expect return "hello world"

but it is ok when I request static file like 'welcome.html'.

now the error scenario is any api request response 404

so, do you guys have any advice?

---

## **new progress**

one gentle man tell me, I couldn't treat .net core as .net framework
I should publish the website via visual studio instead of copy the file to server.

I did it as he say, The original 404 error disappeared.

I encounter another error , but whatever, the new 404 error appear.

another error image display
[image]

it seems my api still didn't work.

Comment: my dev pc window 10

Comment: 1. Have you installed the `.NET Core Hosting Bundle` ? 2. Are you using `in-process` AspNetCoreHostingModel  or `out-of-process` model ? 3. Did you configure the AppPool correctly?

Comment: @itminus yeah, I install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle, using in-process, I configure my app pool with not managed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution( [jacket_zhou from csdn enlightened me](https://blog.csdn.net/jecket_zhou/article/details/89393209))

I just add section environmentVariables which will generated by vs and exists at the publish destination(your server)

here is the code

```
<environmentVariables>
 <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
```

insert this section into appNetCore section

Look like this 
[image]

if the web.config file doesn't exits at the destination server.
here is the solution:
Solution->right click your startop project -> select load project dependencies
-> insert section `<IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>false</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>`
 into section PropertyGroup

Comment: Are you trying to access Swagger APIs that're only available in Development?

Comment: no,I just don't want to publish https, so my startup annotation the hsts line.

Comment: @itminus this is my test project, so I run it with app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

Comment: " just don't want to publish https":In that case, changing the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to development is not a good idea. Remove the `app.UseHsts()` directly.

Comment: @itminus thank you, I will try you solution right now ^-^